# How do you run Java codes in emacs?

Tags: java, emacs

I made a project and named the class the same as the file name. Let say I saved the project and wanted to run it. How do I do this through emacs? I also have jdk installed.

Comment: If you used an IDE for Java, you would press the Run button.  Using an IDE for Java is designed to be much more productive and you can significantly reduce your programming, debugging, profiling and fixes based on code analysis meaning you will produce better quality code, in less time which runs faster. Have a look at IntelliJ CE, Netbeans or Eclipse (all free)

Comment: Would using an additional tool be an option? I use `SCons` to build Java projects and if I then need to run them, I simply run them from Emacs shell. There used to be `JDEE` project, which had an assortment of debuggers and other conveniences, but I think it was abandoned many years ago. That aside, I believe there are modes for editing and running Ant and Maven projects, you could take a look at that.

Comment: @PeterLawrey so do you mean that emacs is not a good text editor for java?

Comment: @syafihakim emacs is perhaps the *best* text editor for Java.  However there is a lot more to writing code than just editing it.  There is running, debugging, profiling, code analysis fixes, refactoring, intelligent code completion, version control/merges, WYSIWYG GUI editing ... This is the one I use http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/

Comment: And if I may add: it is also about what you care the most. Beside being an editor, Emacs can be your shell, your file browser, communicator, time tracker and what not. This is while other tools usually provide none or very limited tools for these tasks, concentrating only on functionality specific to the code editing. I use Emacs to write my Java code because I don't write a lot of it and I desperately need the rest of what Emacs can give, but I also worked in an environment, where using Emacs for Java wasn't really an option. But there's Eclim.

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsEclim some more info on Emacs + Eclim.

Comment: The same way you would run any other compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to have a version of emacs that has some [feature to launch separate applications.](http://www.nongnu.org/emacsdoc-fr/manuel/shell.html) From there, you pass the [command to launch the JVM](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=243) (e.g. java MyClass)

If you are developing a web application, your server *may* be able to dynamically load classes as they change -- it depends on many factors.  If you are developing under that type of environment, then you only need to compile your Java code for the changes to be reflected on the server (assuming the server does dynamic class loading and it works for your development environment -- I've worked on many projects where it doesn't).

Comment: This is not really what you will be doing most of the time when working on a typical Java project. Quite often you will have a Java server running and polling a certain directory for changes, where change would mean that you've recompiled your code and placed a new copy there. Another typical way of working with Java projects is to use Maven toolchain, which normally can launch one or more Java applications as is appropriate to your project.

Comment: @wvxvw: I'm quite aware of how Java development works.  I was addressing his question specifically, which is essentially asking how to launch the JVM from within emacs.

Comment: Well, here are some problems with your link to launching JVM. It only addresses Windows (not a typical system to be used with Emacs). Loading Java classes using bare JVM is complicated and scales very poorly. Java command-line API were written for Windows people (who never use command-line API) :) So if you are after comfort that way is more like masochism, unless you are writing your own launcher or something like that, there's no reason to go down that route.

Comment: I think you are assuming that all java development is web based.  It isn't.  Also, launching the jvm is the same on any system, so whether the link shows "C:\" or "/usr/home" is irrelevant. What he was asking was how can he run his code from emacs.  I'll edit my answer to expand on the different environments, but it's still *an* answer that works.

Comment: Well, you are wrong on both accounts. There are subtle differences difficult to find at a glance. On UNIX platforms Java PATH uses `:` as separator while it uses `;` on MS Windows. `/usr/home` is in no way equivalent to `C:` if anything, it is the equivalent to `C:\Users\` on systems after XP, but there is no isomorphism between the two. The answer as found in your link would need major rewrite if I wanted to use it on my system, and my system is rather typical Linux desktop, when you come to face various other deployment scenarios the sky would be the limit :)

Comment: I didn't mean it to be for web only. Maven is the most popular by far tool for building all sorts of projects in Java world. I personally think it is a bad tool, nevertheless, admit its popularity. Therefore would advise to use it if given a choice between trying to launch Java app from console vs having it launched by Maven. At least Maven provides some kind of OS abstraction.

Comment: If someone can't filter out the differences between Windows environment variables and Unix-type variables, especially someone using some Unix flavor, then they probably have bigger issues.  As to Maven being the most popular build tool, what are your sources for that statement?

Comment: Minor correction: there's not such thing in a typical Linux installation as `/usr/home` probably what was meant by that is a `/home/${USER}`. And I disagree with your last comment as well. No one in their sane mind should not know anything about the inner functioning of MS Windows or it's abominable incarnations. There are a lot more to know about the difference in invoking the `java` from command line then that I mentioned. For example, that `java` doesn't know how to do path expansion. It doesn't process the arguments in the traditional UNIX way and so on.

Comment: According to this survey: http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-build-tools-survey-0 Maven is an uncontested leader in the Java world of build tools. While statistic always lie, at least my claims have certain factual basis.

Comment: Wow.  675 people responded.  Great sample size.  That must be 20 or 30 thousands of a percent at least.

Comment: Which is a good working hypothesis. If you have any survey that is more reliable and renders the results of this survey as nonsensical, you are welcome to share.

Answer (score 3):

I have a few hacks left over from when I was trying out Java.

This one is for the simplest programs consisting from a single file:

```
(defun java-eval-nofocus ()
  "run current program (that requires no input)"
  (interactive)
  (let* ((source (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name))
     (out    (file-name-sans-extension source))
     (class  (concat out ".class")))
    (save-buffer)
    (shell-command (format "rm -f %s && javac %s" class source))
    (if (file-exists-p class)
    (shell-command (format "java %s" out) "*scratch*")
      (progn
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
         (format "javac %s" source))
    (command-execute 'compile)))))
```

This one is for an ant-controlled project:

```
(defun ant-compile ()
  "Traveling up the path, find build.xml file and run compile"
  (interactive)
  (save-buffer)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (while (and (not (file-exists-p "build.xml"))
        (not (equal "/" default-directory)))
      (cd ".."))
    (set (make-local-variable 'compile-command)
     "ant -emacs")
    (call-interactively 'compile)))
```

Some equivalent of these you can probably find in JDEE 
I you can set it up (which I couldn't).

And here are the key bindings I have:

```
(define-key java-mode-map [C-f5] 'java-eval-nofocus)
(define-key java-mode-map [f5] 'ant-compile)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should perhaps install and test out this:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/JavaDevelopmentEnvironment